# How to Throw custom Errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I am trying to use `passport-jwt` strategy for authentication.

Here is my code :-

```js
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email } = req.body;
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ username });
        if (user) {
            throw new Error('User with same username already exists !!');
        }
        const newUser = new User({
            username,
            email
        })
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        newUser.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
        res.json({
            status: 200,
            'Content-Type': 'Application/Json',
            'message': `You have successfully regirstered yourself, ${savedUser.username}!`
        })
    } catch (err) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
        console.log(err.message);
        res.header({
            status: '200',
            'Content-Type': 'Application/Json',
        });
        res.json(err);
    }
});
```

Now this route is working just fine, it's doing all the things till now. The only problem is, When i find an existing user, I want to throw a new error with a custom message. Javascript has this `Error` class which I can use to throw these errors.

The problem occurs when it catches error. When I `console.log(err.message)`, I can see my custom message perfectly. But the `err` object that I am returning in response via `res.json(err)` does not have any `message` but only `statusCode`.

I want to know why this is happening and what's the solution for this ? Right now, I am doing this by doing something like this :-

```
res.json({
    statusCode: 500,
    message : err.message
});
```

But I would like to return the `err` object with both `statusCode` and `message` fields populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the error object to the json method of the response object. But this only takes JSON parseable string as a parameter. What you can do is use -

```
res.json(JSON.stringify(err))
```

and at the place where you are using this response, you need to parse this string as JSON and then convert it into an Error object. You can use the following syntax assuming your front-end also uses javascript

```
err = new Error(JSON.parse(response.data))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own `Error` class which can take more than one parameter in the constructor. This class has to extend base `Error` JavaScript class. For example:

```js
class MyCustomError extends Error {
  constructor(msg, statusCode) {
    super(msg);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.name = MyCustomError.name;
  }
}

function throwCustomError() {
  throw new MyCustomError('Some custom message', 404);
}

try {
  throwCustomError();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
  console.log(error.statusCode);
  console.dir(error);
}
```

> Remember that you have to call `super` on the beginning of the constructor if you are extending another class

Answer (score 0):

Replace the entire catch block with the following line of code.

```
res.status(500).json({
   message: err.message
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of res.json()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) : This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using JSON.stringify().
Now running `JSON.stringify(new Error('custom msg'))` we get `"{}"`